# What is the reason of bumping review limit up to 30 in First Posts, Late Answers, Triage etc.?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, rules

While reviewing in Triage, First Post and Late Answer, I have noticed that its allowing me to review 30 posts in each category. I never saw this before.

However, as far I know:

> Users are limited to reviewing 20 posts per queue each UTC day, unless
> the queue has more than 1,000 items in it, in which case the limit
> bumps up to 40.

But what about the limit of reviewing 30 posts per day? Is something new added?

First Posts and Late Answers review queues remain almost empty all the day.

So, what is the reason of bumping up to 30?

#### My guess:

I am not sure, but it seemed to me that the rules is changed as per follows:

> Users are limited to reviewing **30** posts per queue each UTC day, unless
> the queue has more than 1,000 items in it, in which case the limit
> bumps up to **60**.